# Puppeteersharp Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected

Tags: puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I am trying to navigate a page and then I would like to access some page elements but I got those errors which I sated below.
I shared my code below, you can try it. How can I solve this issue?

Puppeteersharp Version: 2.0.3
Operation System: Windows 10
.Net Library: .Net Core 3.1

```
 class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var page = await GetPageInstance(GetOptions());
                try
                {
                    await page.GoToAsync("https://www.kijk.nl/", new NavigationOptions { WaitUntil = new WaitUntilNavigation[] { WaitUntilNavigation.Load, WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle2 } });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                var possibleCookieAcceptElements = await page.QuerySelectorAllAsync("button");
                Console.Read();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static LaunchOptions GetOptions()
        {
            return new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = false,
                Timeout = 0,
                ExecutablePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
                Args = new string[] {
                    "--no-sandbox",
                    "--disable-notifications",
                    "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                    "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
                    "--lang=en-US,en-GB,en",
                },
                Devtools = false,
                IgnoreHTTPSErrors = true,
                DumpIO = false
            };
        }

        public static async Task<Page> GetPageInstance(LaunchOptions options)
        {

            await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
            var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options);
            var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

            return page;
        }
    }
```

**Error Message that I got for the inner catch block:**

> Navigation failed because browser has disconnected! (NetworkManager
> failed to process Network.requestWillBeSent. Value cannot be null.
> (Parameter 'key'). at
> System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.ThrowKeyNullException()
> at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.GetOrAdd(TKey
> key, Func2 valueFactory) at PuppeteerSharp.Helpers.MultiMap2.Add(TKey
> key, TValue value) at
> PuppeteerSharp.Helpers.AsyncDictionaryHelper`2.GetItemAsync(TKey key)
> at
> PuppeteerSharp.NetworkManager.OnRequestAsync(RequestWillBeSentPayload
> e, String interceptionId) at
> PuppeteerSharp.NetworkManager.OnRequestWillBeSentAsync(RequestWillBeSentPayload
> e) at PuppeteerSharp.NetworkManager.Client_MessageReceived(Object
> sender, MessageEventArgs e))

**Error Message that I got for the outer catch block:**

> Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Session closed. Most likely the
> Page has been closed.Close reason: NetworkManager failed to process
> Network.requestWillBeSent. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key'). at
> System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.ThrowKeyNullException()
> at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.GetOrAdd(TKey
> key, Func2 valueFactory) at PuppeteerSharp.Helpers.MultiMap2.Add(TKey
> key, TValue value) at
> PuppeteerSharp.Helpers.AsyncDictionaryHelper`2.GetItemAsync(TKey key)
> at
> PuppeteerSharp.NetworkManager.OnRequestAsync(RequestWillBeSentPayload
> e, String interceptionId) at
> PuppeteerSharp.NetworkManager.OnRequestWillBeSentAsync(RequestWillBeSentPayload
> e) at PuppeteerSharp.NetworkManager.Client_MessageReceived(Object
> sender, MessageEventArgs e)